How to turn OFF (and ON) a single monitor in a multiple-monitor-system on Kubuntu 24.10 (with Wayland)?
This could be achieved with X easily, but although looking extensively on AskUbuntu and other sites, I did not find a solution for Wayland :-(
The closest I came to was the command kscreen-doctor --dpms off. Unfortunately this turns off all monitors at once. But I'm looking for a more granular command that can turn on/off a single monitor alone.
Some posts suggest that this depends on the compositor. So I checked which compositor Kubuntu 24.10 uses with inxi -Gxx | grep compositor and the output is:

compositor: kwin_wayland driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa

But what command or command-line-tool can I use to achieve the given task?

You might be able to use ddccontrol to talk directly to the monitor, assuming wayland doesn't then immediately override you.

@meuh: Couldn't make it work. Always get DDC/CI on /dev/i2c-29 is unusuable (-1). for all monitors :-(

There is another utility, ddcutil, that does similar things. It is mentioned in kde.org as being used by kde. My 8 year old monitor isnt recognised by either utility, but sudo ddcutil getvcp all did get some i2c responses. Look to change code 0xda to 0x05. You'll need --display 2 for a 2nd monitor found, or  eg --bus 7 for /dev/i2c-7. It did not seem very robust.

Thank you. This did the trick. After getting all monitors with ddcutil detect, I can turn them on(1) and off(2) with ddcutil setvcp -d 3 0xd6 2 (e.g. to turn monitor 3 off).

As suggested in the comments, this can be achieved with the command line utility ddcutil. Install it with
sudo apt install ddcutil

and then enumerate your monitors with
ddcutil detect

The output contains a sequential monitor number like Display 1, a bus address like /dev/i2c-2 and a serial number like 1138753042236 besides other information like the name of the manufacturer and so on.
Display 1
   I2C bus:  /dev/i2c-2
   DRM connector:           card1-HDMI-A-1
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:               IVM - Iiyama North America
      Model:                PLE2483H-DP
      Product code:         24862  (0x611e)
      Serial number:        1138753042236
      Binary serial number: 2236 (0x000008bc)
      Manufacture year:     2017,  Week: 30
   VCP version:         2.1

Each of these values can be used to address the monitor whose state you like to change. To turn a monitor on, pass the value 1 to the VCP 0xD6, and to turn it off, pass the value 2 respectively. So specify the monitor and then the value for ON/OFF.
For example, to turn off display/monitor 1 by sequential number, use
ddcutil setvcp -d 1 0xd6 2

And to turn it off by serial number to make it independent of enumeration, use
ddcutil setvcp --sn 1138753042236 0xd6 2

and to turn it on again
ddcutil setvcp --sn 1138753042236 0xd6 1

There are a lot of other options that can be configured this way, but turning a monitor on and off is the most basic option.
